# QuickBooks PHP API - Get Invoice Share Link

Tags: php, quickbooks

Is that a way to get the `QuickBooks` Invoice Share link via the `PHP API`? I am using "consolibyte.com" `PHP` devkit.

I don't want to download the `pdf`. Just need the Shareable link which I can get from the `QB` invoice detail page.

Please help me on the possibilities.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I am having the same requirement. I want to show a link against each invoice in my site so that when the customer clicks on it, he will be directed to QB where he can make the payment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I could not find any way of getting a Shareable link from QB. But we can connect to QB and request for a pdf version of a particular Invoice.

We can read all invoices for a specific customer and cache the invoiceId (from QB) in our table. Once we want to view the pdf version and since we have already cached the QB Invoice ID we can use,

`$InvoiceService = new \QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Invoice();`
`$InvoiceService->pdf($Context, $realm, $qbInvoieId);`

method to retrieve pdf version. Then we can use a pdf viewer to show it.

Thanks. Hope this answer helps somebody!